# Creating BigQuery database from Sharepoint files

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sharepoint, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I ran into a problem trying to connect data from my company Sharepoint to Google BigQuery. Is there any way to connect the data without using an external connector?

To clarify the situation:
We are trying to connect data from multiple sources and would like to use BigQuery as it provides free options that fit well. Due to the fact that these are a couple of files we are trying to do without third party connectors which are paid. We also want to use Looker Studio as a BI tool which is also free.

I will be glad for any advice and tips on how to proceed.

My colleague and I tried to search the Big Query documentation for the most efficient way to proceed and unfortunately without success. We would like to avoid wasting time on something that might not even work.